# Past-tense noun form of "Archiving"?

Tags: nouns, tenses

I have the following status messages in some code:

> *Deleting Session Data...*
>
> *Delet**ion** complete.*

I want to use the same sentence structure (no alternate structure suggestions, please) to create similar status messages based on the verb **archive** instead of **delete**.

The first one is straightforward:

> *Archiving Session Data...*

But unlike **delete**, **archive** does not seem to have a distinct noun form for the completed act of archiving.  Is the following correct, and are there alternatives to that word form?

> *Archiv**ing** complete.*

Comment: Archiving or filing.

Comment: Or you can use a different clause type: _Completed archiving_ or _Archiving completed_.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your original formulation. Plenty of verbs are transformed into nouns in this way: "Swimming is fun but archiving is boring."  This noun formation using verb + "ing" is called a gerund.

Comment: Ah, right.  I forgot the term for it.  I try to avoid gerunds in user interface and transaction log messages, because they can be easily misread.  My users are focused on a task, not on reading, so the style needs to be terse and distinctive.  My options are further restricted by the application's functional vocabulary (synonyms are a big no no!).

Comment: Wiktionary says that _archival_ can also be used as a noun. The Chicago Manual of Style, however, is not so sure. It acknowledges that it's often used as a noun but suggests that it is "important" to reserve the word as an adjective (I'm not sure why). It is true, though, that the major dictionaries where I searched list only _archiving_ as the noun form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your original formulation. *Archiving* is just as valid as *deletion*.

However, if you don't like the fact that one ends in *-ion* while the other ends in *-ing*, you can switch to a more active use of the verbs.

Keeping the capitalization used in the question, it would look like this:

> ***Deleting*** Session Data …
> Session Data ***deleted***.
>
> ***Archiving*** Session Data …
> Session Data ***archived***.

Comment: Thanks, Jason.  I was hoping to avoid reconstructing the delete message, but I think it's a better alternative to using the gerund form in either of the completion messages.